# Exponential fractional limit

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

I am dealing with the following fraction. I really would need that it still bigger than $0$ as $n\to\infty$ but I think that it is not the case.
\begin{equation}
\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{n/2-1}{\frac{(an^2)^{i}}{i!}}}{e^{an^2}}
\end{equation}
for $a>0$.
Thanks

Comment: Make a crude estimate. The top is (a lot) less than $(n/2)a^{n/2}n^n$. This gets crushed by $e^{an^2}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas How do you get this estimate?

Comment: There are $n/2$ terms. Each is $\le (an^2)^{n/2}$ (I threw away the factorial at the bottom).

Comment: There is a well-known seemingly related limit
$$\frac{\sum\limits_{i=0}^n{\frac{n^i}{i!}}}{e^n}$$
which magically turns out to be $1\over2$. But this is very far from your case. See, they use the summation terms all the way up to the largest one (which is $n^n\over n!$, of course); you use just a very tiny fraction of smallest terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}\frac{x^i}{i!}=e^x \frac{\Gamma (m,x)}{\Gamma(m)}$$
$x=an^2$ and $m=\frac{n}{2}$
$$\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{\frac{n}{2}-1}\frac{x^i}{i!}}{e^{an^2}} = \frac{\Gamma (\frac{n}{2},an^2)}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})}$$
$n\to\infty\quad \begin{cases} \Gamma (\frac{n}{2},an^2)\to 0 \\ \Gamma(\frac{n}{2})\to\infty \end{cases} \quad\implies\quad \frac{\sum_{i=0}^{\frac{n}{2}-1}\frac{x^i}{i!}}{e^{an^2}} \to 0$

Answer (score 0):

Let $b=\max(a,1)$. Then the top is less than or equal to 
$$\frac{n}{2}(bn^2)^{n/2}.\tag{1}$$
For there are $\frac{n}{2}$ terms in the sum, and each is $\le (bn^2)^{n/2}$.

The bottom goes to $\infty$ far faster than (1), for even the $n$-th root of the ratio has limit $0$.